# Combinatorics and probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have 7 interviewees and 14 interviewers. Each interviewee is interviewed by 4 of those 14 interviewees. Is it possible to have every interviewee to be shared by at least 1 interviewer, as to allow for comparative conversations about each interviewee?

Comment: Please re-read your post and make your uses of "interviewee" and "interviewer" consistent and meaningful.  At the same time, could you provide a definition of "shared by" that doesn't make the question as trivial as it seems?

Comment: Are there more conditions here? You can always have the same 4 people interview everyone.

Comment: 0


Thank you for correcting my error. Here it is worded correctly - I have 7 interviewees and 14 interviewers. Each interviewee is interviewed by 4 of those 14 interviewers. Is it possible to have every interviewee to be shared by at least 1 interviewer, as to allow for comparative conversations about each interviewee?

Comment: Roundsquare - the problem with that is two-fold. First, we only have 4 time slots. Second, it's best to utilize more interviewers for "buy in."

Comment: The problem statement is still confusing.  Are you perhaps trying to ask whether every *pair* of interviewees can share an interviewer?

Comment: whuber - not quite. I'm trying to determine, if when the 14 interviewers are discussing each interviewee in our review meeting, that in every case there would be at least one interviewer who interviewed any two interviewees in order to compare.